# DataGridViewRichTextBox row height issue

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am adding a RichTextBox column in my DataGridView.

In the DataGridView the RichTextBox height of the row is set automatically.
and the text does not appear properly.
So how can I set the row Height?

I also tried

```
datagridview1 row1=new datagridview();
row1.height=100;
```

but the row height is not set properly.
Please give me suggestions.

Comment: what you need is to change the height of the rows then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change it with the CellPainting event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = 100;
            }
        }
```

hi again nitesh,about your request i think this is what you want...

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = dataGridView1.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed).Width;
```

or...since we assume at least 1 column exists...

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width;
```

Comment: hi..this is working fine,but i want to change row height or image height based on width.

Comment: Hi Nitesh i edited with 2 possibilities about what i think is what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to set it at design time:

In the properties for the DataGridView, find the RowTemplate property;

click the arrow on the right of RowTemplate, reveailng more details;

edit the Height property.